# hover() event not firing in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/FT4CQ/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.cell').hover(function(){
    $('this').css('background-size','cover');
  });
});
```

am I missing something? I want to hover to zoom out and have full preview of the picture using css.

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery library in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FT4CQ/2/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot to include `jQuery` to your fiddle.

Your code is working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.cell').hover(function(){
    $('this').css('background-size','cover');
  });
});
```

[**Working fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/FT4CQ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

**This work well:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.cell').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('background-size','cover');
  });
});
```

Remove single quotation in $('this'). to change $(this) now it's work well .

Answer (score 0):

This is working code. you did not included Jquery.

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.cell').hover(function(){
    alert('hover work');
  });
});
</script>

    <div class="cell" style="width: 345.53px; height: 210.53px; 

    background-image: 
     url(https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/1521894_10151755196011682_1359230168_n.jpg);  

   position: absolute;-webkit-transition: top 0.5s, left 0.5s; 

   transition: top 0.5s, left 0.5s;" data-delay="2" 
   data-height="200" data-width="331" data-state="move" id="2-2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/FT4CQ/23/

As said, you should not have the single quotation in `$(this)`.
Also, in the example I added a mouseout function, to reset the `background-size`.